# Media.Plugin working only with Google Photo

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, montemagno-media.plugin

In my App I'm using the Media Plugin and I noticed that, when a user tries to upload multiple images by using the method "PickPhotosAsync" using the phone's default gallery it allows him to upload photos one-by-one.
I've also tried using Google Photos and it works just as it's supposed to.
Since not everyone has Google Photos installed I'd like to know wheter it's possible to pick multiple pictures from any gallery application.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/137294/multiple-image-selection-from-gallery) a list of implementations from the Xamarin forums.

To answer the question, the plugin doesn't support it, but you could likely pick from the logic in these examples and roll your own.

Comment: The solution proposed for both Android & iOs doesn't work anymore